# document.getElementsByClassName difficulties

Tags: getelementsbyclassname

I want a function which sets display to none on specific div elements.
Basicly the function should remove everything on buttonclick and set a new content. But my code doesn't seem to work...
Here is the code:

```
function add_product() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `add_product ` function is actually being called (and that your items have the correct class name)? The function appears to work just fine in isolation (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPvdVv for a demo)